# Failed to run Rust project in Docker

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose, dockerfile

So I decided to containerize my Rust project.
This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM rust:slim

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN cargo build --release

CMD ["/usr/src/app/target/debug/solfire"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

What I get after running docker-compose up is:
`` error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1 ``

I believe problem is with Dockerfile, I could not find out how to fix it.

Comment: The error should be larger and explain *why* linking with cc failed, likely a system dependency is missing.

Comment: It looks like this ```error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
346.8   |
346.8   = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.76.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/usr/local/cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

= note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq: No such file or directory
346.8           collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```

Comment: The relevant part of that error is "cannot find -lpq" which is the Postgres library. Try running `apt install libpq-dev` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you, that turned out to be a problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of answering in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `cargo build --release`, the binary will not be in the `target/debug` folder.

Likely, it's in `target/release` and your Dockerfile needs to point at that instead.

---

There's [a section in the Cargo Book about profiles](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html). Running `--release` uses the `release` profile. The book states:

> The output for each profile will be placed in a directory of the same name as the profile in the target directory.